# validates not calling my conditional method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following simple validation code in my model.

```
validates :repeat_period_id, presence: false, unless: :job_spec.nil?

def job_spec_nil?
  logger.debug '* job_spec.nil? = ' + job_spec.nil?.to_s
  job_spec.nil? == true
end
```

`logger.debug` is not added to my log file, so `job_spec_nil?` is not being called. Why?

**EDIT**

I didn't check @Shannon solution before posting my comment. Unfortunately, after changing as per his/her solution the problem remains, ( even though there was clearly a bug in my code ). What could prevent the validation from running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :repeat_period_id, presence: false, unless: :job_spec_nil?
```

Comment: Doh! I used job_spec.nil? instead of job_spec_nil? in my condition. Actually, I could even do better using Proc. According to the rails guides it's better suited for one liner conditions